# List cannot maintain unique elements, but HashSet cannot access via index. How?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, hashset

I'm still new to C#. I want to have a `List<ElementObj>` in a C# application that I am writing. The `List` has to maintain a set of unique elements, ie, no duplicated elements in the `List`.  I also intend to *sort* the list's order according to the `type` attribute of `ElementObj`.

I intend to use the `List` data structure from `System.Collections.Generics`. But `List` don't maintain *uniqueness* on its own. So, every time before I add an element to the list, I may have to loop through the entire list to check if an element already exists in the `List`. This doesn't sound very efficient.

I read that I could use a `HashSet`. This will ensure uniqueness of the elements in the set. But, the problem is I cannot access the elements in `HashSet` through an index, say `myHashSet[0]`.

In a situation like this, what would be the best data structure or effective solution to it?

Comment: So I would store 2 copies of the same data? Then when I have to alter the list, I would have to maintain both the Set and List, wouldn't it?

Comment: Would this be an effective solution? I mean having an extra copy of the same data and having to maintain the double copy of the data. I think it sounds cool, and really makes the job done in an easier manner. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually need random access to the elements? I find that I don't need this when working with sets. [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) might do the trick.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Why would you not need to access their index when working with Sets? If you don't access them via their index, then, how would you pick the elements stored in the Set to work with?

Comment: You can iterate over the set. My question was about *random* access, which you don't need for most purposes.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Ahh...I see. Thank you so much! Just one thing though, suppose I want to get an element of index 100. With a List, I just say list[100]. If I use a Set with Iterator, I would have to loop through to get the 100th element, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, and if accessing arbitrary elements by their position is a specific requirement of your problem, then you clearly need random access. I was questioning whether that is actually the case. The normal way to access elements from a set is by iterating over the set directly using `foreach` (or calling `GetEnumerator` directly) or passing it to any method that accepts an `IEnumerable<ElementObj>`.

Comment: OTOH, the most common reason for populating a set is to perform membership tests or, more generally, set operations, none of which require direct element access.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Thank you so much! It has become so much clearer to me now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @CuongLe I tried to use ElementAt but Visual Studio highlights that the method is invalid.

Comment: Well, don't understand much, just make it work on my VS

Comment: @CuongLe: That's a LINQ extension method that performs a linear scan to reach the desired element. It isn't true random access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create my own collection class which keeps the objects internally in both a hashset and a list.

```
public class HashList<T> {
   private HashSet<T> _hashSet;
   private List<T> _list;

   public T this[int i]
   {
       return _list[i];
   }

   public void add(T item) 
   {
       if (_hashSet.add(item))
          _list.add(item);
   }
}
```